# NodeJS Worker as slow/slower than as regular Single Thread Program

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, worker

Before anything, I know that I WANT to make my own database system, I already made one in the past that worked perfectly, I am simply looking to take on difficult challenges.

This Database system will be memory based.
I am looking for methods to read / write data the most efficient way and for that I made a couple of benchmarks, here are the code/results:

```js
// 1. JSON array system | 84.289ms
let testDataJson = new Array(10000000).fill({ id: 1, username: "TestUsername", password: "MyPassword1234", email : "email@gmail.com" })
testDataJson.push({ username: "FoundUsername" }); // Insert matching element

console.time("dataJson");
console.log(testDataJson.find(elem => elem.username === "FoundUsername");
console.timeEnd("dataJson");
```

```js
// 2. TEXT array system | 86.041ms
let testDataText = new Array(10000000).fill(`1|TestUsername|MyPassword1234|email@gmail.com`.split("|"));
testDataText.push(`|FoundUsername||`.split("|"));

console.time("dataText");
console.log(testDataText.find(elem => elem[1] === "FoundUsername");
console.timeEnd("dataText");
```

Now onto the problematic part, I decided for this version to work using NodeJS Workers to spread the load accross multiples threads.
For that I am spreading the array into x amount of workers and split the data array.
I am then loading in each worker memory its designated data block and wait 3 seconds to let everything settle. I then run the search, and the result is, quite bad, here is my code

```js
// PROGRAM CODE | 56.698ms
function loadThreads()
{
    let dataChunks = fs.readFileSync("./db.txt", 'utf-8').split("\n");
    let workersParts = chunkArrayInGroups(dataChunks, 2000000); // File is 10 000 000 Lines, resulting in 5 workers
    for (let workerPart of workersParts)
    {
        const worker = new Worker("./dbTester_thread.js", { workerData: workerPart.join("\n") });
        threads.push(worker);
    }
}

function performSearch()
{
    console.time("threadTest");
    for (let thread of threads)
    {
        thread.on('message', (message) => {
            console.timeEnd("threadTest")
        });
        thread.postMessage("HelloMan")
    }

}

// THREAD CODE
const { parentPort, workerData } = require('node:worker_threads');

let data = workerData.split("\n").map(line => line.split(","));
parentPort.on('message', (message) => 
{
  let found = data.find(line => line[1] === message);
  if (found) parentPort.postMessage("FOUND");
});
```

My first theory was that maybe parentPort.postMessage is poorly optimised and takes x amount of time to fully contact the main thread, but after trying an immediate postMessage after any message reception, the delay of an instant response was 0.444ms so I am out of explainations.

I am out of solutions besides what I placed up there

Comment: Also I am wondering if the problem doesn't simply comes from my lack of understanding of the NodeJS Worker system ? But from what I remember a Worker is a separate process and should have all the spread balanced properly

Comment: Workers aren't separate *processes*, but they are separate threads within the process, which is probably what you meant and what you want. Because they're separate threads they can run truly concurrently on multiple CPU cores.

Comment: Do you think that the limitation comes from the NodejS Process itself ? What if the limitation comes from the memory reading speed ? Maybe it has ap hysical cap that is shared accross all threads leading to no improvement in reading speed for example

Comment: I'm struggling to see what speed issue you're having. Is it startup? Or during search? If search, how long is the search taking?

Comment: Separately: Rather than an arbitrary three-second delay, have the workers tell the parent when they're ready to work. That's the usual pattern if the worker has init it needs to do before it's ready for stuff.

Comment: The search is taking 56.698ms accross 5 workers. Conscidering 1 of the workers only has to read 2 millons lines, you would expect him to return much earlier than that, but the result is that its almost the same as a single thread find (like my first 2 examples). Also yes I know the delay issue, I already evaluated that it was taking 1 second for the worker to load, I just made the examples as simple as possible

Comment: I don't know if it's the issue, but *an* issue is that the timing code may be problematic. You're calling `console.time` just once, but then calling `console.timeEnd` when each worker replies. You may want to do a separate timer per thread: https://pastebin.com/YwPiLHnh But maybe you know it'll work the way it is. I'd also suggest making sure the thread sends a reponse whether it finds the result or not (different responses, of course), but I assume for your simple timing tests you've included the target string at the end of ... what ... the file as a whole? Each part? Anyway, good luck!